# Logic Field Division Or Diagram

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

I'm very confused on how the field of logic is divided and which are its main branches.
My researches for a clean diagram have gone nowhere, so stackexchange is my last resort.
I know logic can be divided in standard (or classical) and non-standard (or non-classical).
 Anyway, Wikipedia article on [Classical logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_logic) says "Classical logic  is an intensively studied and widely used class of formal logics". This seem to imply that classical logics are just a class of formal logics (or mathematical logics). Moreover, it seems to presume a more primitive distinction between formal and non-formal logics.
If you keep on reading wikipedia article on [Mathematical logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_logic), you discover that mathematical logic is considered to be divided in :
Proof theory, model theory, set theroy and recursion (computability) theory.
Category theory is excluded from this division, and reasons are provided to support this choice.
Moreover, the article before diving in the discussion of these 4 branches, shows a confusing paragraph on "Fromal logic systems" in which classical and non-classical logics are discussed.
It's not clear under what division fall things like traditional logic, propositional logic and first-order logic.
And again considering the popular first-order logic as a "standard", "one-sorted","first-order" logic, I can talk about many-sorted or higher order logics. I'm just wondering how much more there is.
I'm in need of some sort of calrification: a diagram, a nested list... whatever can help giving a mental order for all this divisions.

Comment: Why are you in need of this?

Comment: More than one "dimensions".... The "classical" organization of topics is the fourfold you discussed; see the authoritative (but olk): [Handbook of ML](https://books.google.it/books?id=b0Fvrw9tBcMC&printsec=frontcover). But the 17 volumes of the 2nd ed of the [Handbook of Philosophical Logic](http://www.springer.com/series/6024) have a much more complex organization.

Comment: @DerekElkins I like to see where I am and where I can go when I'm studying something. A little bit like you may  want to know where you are and where you can go when you are making a trip :)

Comment: For a short modern overview, see JC Beall & Shay Allen Logan, [Logic: The Basics](https://www.routledge.com/Logic-The-Basics-2nd-Edition/Beall-Logan/p/book/9781138852273), Routledge (2nd ed 2017).